# unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, byte, pwntools

I am trying to decrypt a one time pad, and looking at a bunch of resourses led me to putting together this script.

```
File "p.py", line 37, in <module>
    key.append( ord(message[e])^encoded[e] )
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'int' and 'str'
```

from a debugger I am getting:
`BytesWarning: Text is not bytes`

So i know I need to reformat some strings somewhere but I am struggling on finding a solution.

```
from pwn import *

import binascii

offset = 50000 - 32

p = remote('mercury.picoctf.net', 58913)

print(p.recvline())
print(p.recvline())
encrypted_flag = p.recvline().strip()

print(encrypted_flag)

p.recvuntil('?')
p.sendline('A'offset)

p.recvuntil('?')

p.sendline('A'32)

p.recvline()

encoded = p.recvline().strip()

print(encoded)

encoded = binascii.unhexlify(encoded)

print(encoded)

message = 'A'*32

key = []

for e in range(len(encoded)):
    key.append( ord(message[e])^encoded[e] )

print(key)

decoded_flag = []

encrypted_flag = binascii.unhexlify(encrypted_flag)

for i in range(32):
    decoded_flag.append( chr(key[i]^encrypted_flag[i]) )

flag = ''.join(decoded_flag)

print(flag)
```

Comment: Note: when you are building up your `key` list, use a list comprehension. `key = [ord(message[e]) ^ encoded[e] for e in range(len(encoded))]`

Comment: What are the values printed out for `encrypted_flag` and `encoded`?